# Javascript game engine that can work 'seamlessly' with react-native

Tags: javascript, html-canvas, mobile, webgl

I have experience with Unity, but I don't like the fact that Unity compiles your game directly into APK (or IOS equivalent). I want to modify the game to provide chat interface for multiplayer mode etc. So, I thought of doing it the other way - create an app and embed a multiplayer game within it. This approach meant that I had to develop for Android and iOS, separately. I then came across the React-Native library, a mobile extension of the popular React framework.

I have decided to create an app using React-Native, but now I am confused as to which game engine I should use. I think, since React-Native is JavaScript, the game engine needs to be in JavaScript for seamless integration. I am planning to use WebView to embed the game in my react-native app.

Can anyone suggest a good JavaScript game engine that can be used along with react-native? I have done some research on Phaser and Pixi, but they use WebGL for rendering and, I read somewhere that WebView doesn't have great support for WébGL or Canvas.

Comment: I recommend reading the [help].

Comment: Yeah, as Almo said, "I need a list" type of question is too broad and their answers do not age well because they become obsolete. Sites like [GDnet](http://gamedev.net) are a bit better suited for this kind of discussion. If you have more precise question, you're more than welcome to come back and ask them here :)

Comment: chat interface for multiplayer mode also possible with unity , you only need to figure out how .

Comment: ok thanks I will try different forums for now and once I have precise questions will be back here.  Thanks for all your replies.

Comment: Your question is nebulous, but I can say for sure that phaser uses WebGL and that it is supported on mobile, including in a WebView, so your app should be fine.

Comment: Thanks @Bob_Gneu.  I made a test run with Canvas (using an existing HTML5 game) in webView and it did work well.

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend using [phaser](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjn15nFmfTQAhWL5YMKHRvgAQYQFggdMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fphaser.io%2F&usg=AFQjCNHi-e37QHh9Z6k6NVNsLOdv5nm5Vw&sig2=elJDZIc1zqdjo2L7O27RrA&bvm=bv.141320020,d.amc), it should work

Comment: Can you tell us *why* asker should use phaser? What does it do? How does it solve the problem? What do you mean by it *should* work? If you are not sure, this should probably be a comment.